# Android Java - Reading in Text File of Integers, Storing Integers in Array, and Graphing Them

Tags: java, android, arrays

So, for my code, what I am trying to do is read in a .txt file that contains integers, store those integers into an array list via parseInt(), and then graphing those points via GraphView. I have done some debugging for my code and I have noticed that none of the points are being graphed and when I test out my code by printing the values for my array list via label, it crashes my app. I am unsure of what is going on, as I think I am on the right track in this process. Here is my code below. *NOTE: I used TextView labels as tests to determine if the data is actually read in (in this case it's not). Thanks in advance!

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.anjanarajagopal.graph;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private static final String FILENAME = "data.txt";
    private TextView textview1;
    private TextView textview2;
    private TextView textview3;
    private TextView textview4;
    private TextView textview5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            if(inputStream != null){
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String line;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(line);
                    data.add(i);
                }
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", FILENAME);
            e.printStackTrace();
            //return null;
        }
        //for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        //{
        //    int value = data.get(i);
        //    System.out.print(value + " ");
        //}
        //textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //textview2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //textview3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        //textview4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        //textview5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        //textview1.setText(Integer.toString(data.get(0)));
        //textview2.setText(Integer.toString(data.get(1)));
        //textview3.setText(Integer.toString(data.get(2)));
        //textview4.setText(Integer.toString(data.get(3)));
        //textview5.setText(Integer.toString(data.get(4)));

        GraphView graph;
        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{
                    new DataPoint(i, data.get(i))
            });
            graph.addSeries(series);
        }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

data.txt
142
149
146
142
152
165
178
188
171
169
179
155
129
117
125
155
204
251
270
265

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />
<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/graph" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world!"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A little advice: use a database, instead of a text file, to store your data.

Answer (score -2):

In your particular case you should put data.txt in **src/main/assets** folder. Then instead of line

```
InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
```

use the following line

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(FILENAME);
```

Comment: This post should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do a comment.

Comment: It's not a valid reason to post a non-answer.

Comment: The file is one integer per line.

Comment: OK, do you have any stacktrace on the console?

Comment: I took a look at the console and apparently, it is having an error reading data.txt, as the file is not found. But I have data.txt saved under the same folder as my project.